# NAT box with two external interfaces and two network namespaces

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, nat, network-namespaces

I have an ARM embedded system with kernel 4.9.62 that has two physical interfaces as shown below:

```
                                                      ________
                              +------------+         /
                              |            |        |
       +----------------------+ Subnet   1 +--------|
       |10.0.0.180            |10.0.0.1    |       /
+------+-------+              +------------+      |
|    eth0      |                                  /
|              |                                  |
|   Host       |                                  |     Internet
|              |                                  |
|    wlan0     |                                  \
+------+-------+              +------------+       |
       |10.0.10.250           |            |       \
       +----------------------+ Subnet 2   +-------|
                              |10.0.10.1   |       |
                              +------------+       \________

>ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:20:c4:04:c2:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:da:38:d3:3e:4e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 

>ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0
default via 10.0.10.1 dev wlan0  metric 2
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.180
10.0.10.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.10.250
```

What I'm trying to do is add two network namespaces so that I can run network tests targeted out either of the two interfaces. So what I'd like the result to be is:

```
>ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.4.46): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.4.46: seq=0 ttl=56 time=53.575 ms

>ip netns exec eth_ns ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.4.46): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.4.46: seq=0 ttl=55 time=53.496 ms

>ip netns exec wlan_ns ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.4.110): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.4.110: seq=0 ttl=55 time=56.443 ms
```

Currently what I've tried is the following script to setup two network namespaces and each namespace with one end of a veth pair while the other end of the veth pair is nat'd to the appropriate physical interface:

```
# ############################################
# Create the ethernet namespace
ip netns add eth_ns

# Create veth link.
ip link add v-eth1 type veth peer name v-peer1

# Add peer-1 to NS.
ip link set v-peer1 netns eth_ns

# Setup IP address of v-eth1.
ip addr add 10.200.1.1/24 dev v-eth1
ip link set v-eth1 up

# Setup IP address of v-peer1.
ip netns exec eth_ns ip addr add 10.200.1.2/24 dev v-peer1
ip netns exec eth_ns ip link set v-peer1 up
ip netns exec eth_ns ip link set lo up
ip netns exec eth_ns ip route add default via 10.200.1.1


# ############################################
# Create the wlan namespace
ip netns add wlan_ns

# Create veth link.
ip link add v-wlan1 type veth peer name v-peer2

# Add peer-2 to NS.
ip link set v-peer2 netns wlan_ns

# Setup IP address of v-wlan1.
ip addr add 10.200.2.1/24 dev v-wlan1
ip link set v-wlan1 up

# Setup IP address of v-peer2.
ip netns exec wlan_ns ip addr add 10.200.2.2/24 dev v-peer2
ip netns exec wlan_ns ip link set v-peer2 up
ip netns exec wlan_ns ip link set lo up
ip netns exec wlan_ns ip route add default via 10.200.2.1


# ############################################
# Share internet access between host and NS.

# Enable IP-forwarding.
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Flush forward rules, policy DROP by default. Flush nat rules.
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F


# ############################################
# Enable masquerading of 10.200.1.0.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.1.0/255.255.255.0 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
# Allow forwarding between eth0 and v-eth1.
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o v-eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i v-eth1 -j ACCEPT


# ############################################
# Enable masquerading of 10.200.2.0.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.2.0/255.255.255.0 -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
# Allow forwarding between wlan0 and v-wlan1.
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o v-wlan1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o wlan0 -i v-wlan1 -j ACCEPT
```

The result is that the following first two commands work as expected, while the third fails:

```
>ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.4.46): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.4.46: seq=0 ttl=56 time=53.575 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.4.46: seq=1 ttl=56 time=53.751 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.4.46: seq=2 ttl=56 time=52.709 ms

>ip netns exec eth_ns ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.4.46): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.4.46: seq=0 ttl=55 time=53.496 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.4.46: seq=1 ttl=55 time=52.967 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.4.46: seq=2 ttl=55 time=53.038 ms

>ip netns exec wlan_ns ping google.com
ping: bad address 'google.com'
```

I can ping the default router from wlan_ns:

```
>ip netns exec wlan_ns ping 10.0.10.1
PING 10.0.10.1 (10.0.10.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.10.1: seq=0 ttl=63 time=5.232 ms
```

But nothing that needs routed works via wlan_ns. I'm sure this is an issue with my two default routes as I can delete the 10.0.0.1 default route and then wlan_ns works.

So how do I configure the routing tables or iptables to make both eth_ns and wlan_ns work at the same time?

Comment: Your two namespaces are routed by the host, which is connected twice to internet, with the host routing them. The problem becomes a policy routing problem with a multi-homed router (the host). It's not really a namespace issue as this problem would be the same with actual systems behind the host/router sitting on 4 nets (10.0.0.0/24 for internet via ethernet, 10.0.10.0/24 for internet via wireless, 10.200.1.0/24 for lan that should go via ethernet, and 10.200.2.0/24 for lan that should go via wireless). Policy routing (involving the use of `ip rule`) solves this. Are you still interested?